# Using prefetch_related_objects on nonhomogenous objects with a shared relationship

Tags: django, django-models

ModelA has a Many-to-One relationship to ModelC

ModelB has a Many-to-One relationship to ModelC

I have a situation where I need to access the related objects through both like `model_a_instance.model_c` and `model_b_instance.model_c` and I don't want to fire off N additional queries.  I found that using `prefetch_related_objects(list_of_model_a_instances + list_of_model_b_instances, 'model_c')` works as expected.  However, peaking into prefetch_related_objects code I noted this.

```py
# We assume that objects retrieved are homogeneous (which is the premise
# of prefetch_related), so what applies to first object applies to all.
first_obj = obj_list[0]
```

Are there any side effects I should be worried about here?  I did notice that the related instances are identical.

```py
list_of_model_a_instances[0].model_c is list_of_model_b_instances[0].model_c
Out[1]: True
```

So, downstream code will need to not unexpectedly modify the related objects to prevent undefined behavior.

Anything else I should be worried about here?